# loose coupling related to composition

Tags: oop, composition, loose-coupling, tightly-coupled-code

After searching  different forums related to tight coupling (when a group of classes are highly dependent on one another)
Example1

```
 class CustomerRepository
        {
            private readonly Database database;

            public CustomerRepository(Database database)
            {
                this.database = database;
            }

            public void Add(string CustomerName)
            {
                database.AddRow("Customer", CustomerName);
            }
        }
        class Database
        {
            public void AddRow(string Table, string Value)
            {
            }
        }
```

Above class CustomerRepository is dependent on Database class so they are tightly coupled .and i think  this class is also an example of Compostion  ,then i searched for loose coupling so changing the above class so that tight coupling dependency is removed.
Example2

```
   class CustomerRepository
        {
            private readonly IDatabase database;

            public CustomerRepository(IDatabase database)
            {
                this.database = database;
            }

            public void Add(string CustomerName)
            {
                database.AddRow("Customer", CustomerName);
            }
        }

        interface IDatabase
        {
            void AddRow(string Table, string Value);
        }

        class Database : IDatabase
        {
            public void AddRow(string Table, string Value)
            {
            }
        }
```

I have searched that composition support loose coupling now my question is how example1 is tightly coupled as it were based on composition? secondly what is the relation between loose coupling and composition?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is not really tight coupling. Tight coupling would be this:

```
class CustomerRepository {
    private readonly Database database;

    public CustomerRepository() {
        this.database = new Database;
    }
}
```

The class has a hardcoded dependency on a specific `Database` class which cannot be substituted. That's really tight coupling.

The composition example you're showing is already loosely coupled, since it's entirely possible to substitute the dependency being injected into the constructor by any other `Database` inheriting class.

Your second example is even more loosely coupled, since it uses an interface instead of a concrete class; but that's something of a minor detail.

Comment: thanks,i want to know what is the relationship between loose coupling and compostion? 

how compostion support loose coupling as it has completed access of class??

Comment: Composition describes putting an instance of one class as property on another class. That second class is "composed of" itself and another class; i.e. it can use the functionality of other classes without "being" another class (like `extend` would do). "Loose coupling" generally describes the idea of *not hardcoding dependencies* and allowing them to be substituted. Composition is one typical way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

[@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s explains most of your questions. I am just adding my 2 cents to his answer.

Both examples are loosely coupled but to different degrees.

Example -1 You are allowed to inject object of concrete type via its constructor.

Example -2 You are allowed to inject an objecto of abstract type via its constructor.

What makes the example 2 more loosly coupled is the due to [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). It's main idea is - ***one should “Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.”***

Second example depends on interface and not on a Concrete class like the first one. Now comes the confusion -why interface is special why not a class both of them do the same thing?

Lets assume tomorrow if you want to delete `Database` Class and replace it with new class `FlatFile`, you need to change `CustomerRepository` class in the first example but not the second. In the second example the person who will create an instance of `CustomerRepository` only should worry replacing `Database` class with `FlatFile` Class. This is the meaning of loose copling changing `Database` class should not force you to change `CustomerRepository` class.

To answer your last question

> *what is the relation between loose coupling and composition?*

There is no direct relation, you can still use composition and mess up the coupling between class by not implementing the Dependency inversion principle. So the right question you should ask is -

> *How to make a tightly coupled code to loosely coupled?*

Follow Dependency inversion principle.